# Deployment error ThemeLayout's label must be unique

Tags: community, deployment, metadata-api

I am trying to use experience bundles in order to deploy communities from one sandbox to the other, so I retrieved the Experience, CustomSite and Network folder with package.xml in VSCode . But the deployment fails with the following error[image]

So I tried , deducing the error and went to the individual json files, and changed the label from **Customer Service** to **Customer Service Employer**, **Customer Service Admin** and **Customer Service Participant**.( Considering all the communities are using the same theme i.e Customer Service)

[image]

[image]

Still I receive the same error !

[image]

Has anyone faced the same issue before?

Comment: Can you please check,if you have changed the DeveloperName of the theme along with the label since the developerName should be unique here.

Reference:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm

If you haven't changed already then I would suggest you to try by changing the developerName of the themes listed in the error.

Comment: It worked ,Thanks